# How to use Python Interpreter in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-prompt

I have done something to my cmd prompt/VS Code and now I don't know how to run my Python code. Usually, I type code into VS code, save it as a .py file and run in the command prompt to get the output. But now, for some reason, when I try to run my .py file in cmd prompt, it redirects me back to VS code! How can I fix my cmd prompt to normally run again?

Also, I noticed that I can run code in Python Interpreter, which is integrated into VS Code. But when I wrote a simple code:

```
x = 5
print(x)
```

the Python interpreter outputs:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I feel like a child lost in a big mall. Please somebody help me  - I can't learn further if I don't know how to run my code.

Comment: What command are you using to run the file?

Comment: You need to install Python extension from the vs code marketplace first. After you did that you need to press F1 and start typing Select Interpreter in the textbox that appeared. Click on the option and select the relevant interpreter. Hope that helps.

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_run-hello-world